# checking out svn project in emacs

Tags: svn, version-control, emacs

I'm using emacs for almost all my work. I have also implemented version control on my code via svn. I know there is a version control capabilities for emacs but I can't find how to checkout  a project. Does any of you know how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `M-x svn-checkout`. The function is part of psvn.el. Find it at http://www.xsteve.at/prg/emacs/psvn.el.

Answer (score 2):

There is a remote repository browser called Sublain but it is rather crude and the documentation is pretty much nonexistent. http://hp.vector.co.jp/authors/VA023689/sublain/